# Concurrent requests to ruby REST API not possible

Tags: mysql, ruby, concurrency, sinatra

I am trying to create some small REST API using *ruby* with *Sinatra* gem running on *thin* server. The point is to get an idea about how easy/hard is to build such REST API consisting of micro web services and to compare this with other programming languages / technologies available at Amazon's AWS. I have created one quite easily, here's the code (just minimal working project, not yet considering any kind of optimization):

```ruby
require 'sinatra'
require 'mysql'
require 'json'

set :environment, :development

db_host = 'HOST_URL'
db_user = 'USER'
db_pass = 'PASSWORD'
db_name = 'DB_NAME'
db_enc  = 'utf8'

select = 'SELECT * FROM table1 LIMIT 30'

db = Mysql.init
db.options Mysql::SET_CHARSET_NAME, db_enc
db = db.real_connect db_host, db_user, db_pass, db_name

get '/brands' do
    rs = db.query select
    #db.close
    result = []
    rs.each_hash do |row|
        result.push row
    end
    result.to_json
end
```

Running this with `ruby my_ws.rb` starts *Sinatra* running on *thin*, **no problem**.

Using `curl` from my terminal like `curl --get localhost:4567/brands` is also not a problem returning the desired JSON response.

The real problem I am tackling now for few hours already (and searching on Google of course, reading lot of resources also here on SO) is when I try to *benchmark* the micro WS using **Siege** with more concurrent users:

> sudo siege -b http://localhost:4567/brands -c2 -r2

This should run in *benchnark* mode issuing 2 concurrent request (`-c2` switch) 2 times (`-r2` switch). In this case I always get an error in the console stating `Mysql::ProtocolError - invalid packet: sequence number mismatch(102 != 2(expected)):` while the number `102` is always different on each run. If I run the benchmark only for one user (one concurrent request, i.e. no concurrency at all) I can run it even 1000 times with no errors (`sudo siege -b http://localhost:4567/brands -c1 -r1000`).

I tried adding manual threading into my code like:

```ruby
get '/brands' do
    th = Thread.new do
        rs = db.query select
        #db.close
        result = []
        rs.each_hash do |row|
            result.push row
        end
        result.to_json
    end
    th.join
    th.value
end
```

but with no help.

From what I have found:

- Sinatra is multithreaded by default
- thin is also multithreaded if run from Sinatra if run by `ruby script.rb`
- multithreading seems to have no effect on DB queries - here it looks like no concurrency is possible

I'm using `ruby-mysql` gem as I have found out it's newer then (just) `mysql` gem but in the end have no idea which one to use (found old articles to use `mysql` and some other to use `ruby-mysql` instead).

**Any idea on how to run concurrent requests to my REST API?** I need to benchmark and compare it with other languages (PHP, Python, Scala, ...).

Comment: I would try a different mysql adapter, maybe it is not thread safe. What ruby runtime do you use ?

Comment: Should be latest, `ruby -v` gives me `ruby 2.1.2p95 (2014-05-08) [x86_64-linux-gnu]`.

Comment: Which other adapters should I try? Pure `mysql` has problems with setting the character set and encoding conversions. That was the reason I replaced it with `ruby-mysql` which is in version 2.9.13.

Comment: I've always used [mysql2](https://github.com/brianmario/mysql2) and it's a pretty active project. Some stuff are missing though (like no prepare statement)

Comment: Yes, directly looking at the `mysql2` on GH... I'll give it a try and check back.

Comment: Oh my bad, prepare statement are now apparently available \o/ (that's quite recent)

Comment: OK, seems like with `mysql2` adapter it not only works, but even **is 4times faster**!!!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is solved with two fixes.

The first one is by replacing the mysql adapter with `mysql2`.

The second one was the real cause of the problem: the MySQL connection was created once for runtime before the I could even dive into the thread (i.e. before the code for route was executed) causing (logically) connection locks.

Now with `mysql2` and connection to DB moved under the route execution it is all working perfectly fine even for 250 concurrent requests! The final code:

```ruby
require 'sinatra'
require 'mysql2'
require 'json'

set :environment, :development

db_host = 'HOST_URL'
db_user = 'USER'
db_pass = 'PASSWORD'
db_name = 'DB_NAME'
db_enc  = 'utf8'

select = 'SELECT * FROM table1 LIMIT 30'

get '/brands' do
    result = []
    Mysql2::Client.new(:host => db_host, :username => db_user, :password => db_pass, :database => db_name, :encoding => db_enc).query(select).each do |row|
      result.push row
    end
    result.to_json
end
```

Running `sudo siege -b http://localhost:4567/brands -c250 -r4` gives me now:

```
Transactions:             1000 hits
Availability:             100.00 %
Elapsed time:             1.54 secs
Data transferred:         2.40 MB
Response time:            0.27 secs
Transaction rate:         649.35 trans/sec
Throughput:               1.56 MB/sec
Concurrency:              175.15
Successful transactions:  1000
Failed transactions:      0
Longest transaction:      1.23
Shortest transaction:     0.03
```